# Replace cxf parameters with spring (dynamically)

Tags: spring, cxf

I have following `cxf.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
      xmlns:http="http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http/configuration"
      xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd
              http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http/configuration
      http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/http-conf.xsd">
    <http:conduit name="http://localhost:8080/mockInterfaceSoap">
        <http:client ReceiveTimeout="5000" />
    </http:conduit>
</beans>
```

Is there any way to replace hardcoded `ReceiveTimeout` parameter value with spring?

EDIT:
I want to change it dynamically in runtime. Change is quite rare so app can change existing endpoint or create new one.

Comment: you can read it from a property file.. or do you want dynamic behaviour at runtime ?

Comment: Property file is not a problem. I need to change it dynamic at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient helps. I have found some time ago a reference to it and have used it in the following example:

```
String endpointAddress = "*";
WebClient client = WebClient.create(endpointAddress);
HTTPConduit httpConduit = WebClient.getConfig(client).getHttpConduit();
httpConduit.setTlsClientParameters(new TLSClientParameters());
httpConduit.getTlsClientParameters().setUseHttpsURLConnectionDefaultHostnameVerifier(true);
httpConduit.getTlsClientParameters().setUseHttpsURLConnectionDefaultSslSocketFactory(true);
return httpConduit;
```

Comment: Thank you, but question is almost year old. I do not work on the same platform anymore. Golden Shovel Award for you: http://www.teamsandtastic.com/IMAGES/1-Gold.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You can use it as follows.

```
<jaxrs-client:client id="clientId" serviceName="clientServiceName"
                 address="${urlService}" >
</<jaxrs-client:client>

<http-conf:conduit  name="*clientServiceName*.http-conduit" >
     <http-conf:client ReceiveTimeout="1"/>
</http-conf:conduit>
```

Comment: Oh my god! How have you ended here? This question is over 5 years old. Golden Shovel Award for you: teamsandtastic.com/IMAGES/1-Gold.jpg